# How do I remove the Python3 tkinter ttk.CheckButton dashed line that appears after selecting the checkbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Is there any way to remove the dashed outline that appears when clicking the text of the ttk.Checkbutton object while using the 'default' theme?

example.)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
master = Tk()
style = ttk.Style()            # print(self.style.theme_names())
style.theme_use('default')
var = IntVar()
c = ttk.Checkbutton(master, text="Click My Text", variable=var)
c.pack()
mainloop()
```

If not is there any way of changing the the background button color of the standard theme used while running on windows? (Unfortunately for this project I cannot consider using any other GUI packages)

```
OS: Windows 10
Python: 3.5.1
Frustration level: one bajillion
```

Comment: The dashed outline serves a purpose: it lets the user know which button has the keyboard focus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I am wrong but, there doesn't seem to be a "dash off" option. However, there are still some options.

You could set the 'takefocus' option to False. This will stop the dashed outline showing, but would also remove the ability to tab between controls.

```
c = ttk.Checkbutton(master, text="Click My Text", variable=var, takefocus=False)
```

Another option would be to change the color of the dash to match the background:

```
style.configure('TCheckbutton', focuscolor=style.configure(".")["background"])
```

This kind of works, but you will need to play with the highlight color too so it's always invisible.

**EDIT**

While knocking up a small example to help with one of the comments, I found a slightly easier way to do this. Using cget() we can get the value of a property. This can be used instead of fiddling with the style and is easier to read and understand.

Using cget the above example becomes:

```
style.configure('TCheckbutton', focuscolor=master.cget("background"))
```

This simply sets the focus colour equal to the background colour of the master object (The window).

As requested, here is a full example based on the original code from the question:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
master = Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('default')

style.configure('TCheckbutton', focuscolor=master.cget("background"))
style.configure('TCheckbutton', activebackground=master.cget("background"))
style.configure('TCheckbutton', background=master.cget("background"))

var = IntVar()
c = ttk.Checkbutton(master, text="Click My Text", variable=var)
c.pack()
mainloop()
```

Here we set the focuscolor, activebackground and background colors equal to the background of the main window (master). This has the effect of removing the dashed border.

However, the dashed border is there for a reason. It shows the user which control has focus. When there is only one control on the window it looks a little strange. But when you have several it allows users to navigate through your app using the keyboard easier than it does without.

Comment: Hi Andrew,

Is there any way you can show me a working version because I am having trouble getting your suggestion to work. The second piece of code you provided seems to change the dash color from black to white but I am not sure how I would get it to match the background color of the label element. Also can you explain what the "." parameter refers to?

Comment: I have managed to get my project to have the style I wanted however I am not entirely sure I understand how it works. I tried to apply the apply the concepts to the mini example above but was unsuccessful. Given that I was able to utilize Andrew's answer to get the results I was looking for I am marking this as answered however I truly wish someone provided a more concrete example for those of us 'me' who will struggle with this in the future. Thank you Andrew for steering me in the right path towards a working solution.

Comment: I have edited the post to include an example based on your own code. I hope this helps. @krazynhazy