# tkinter align button within frame with grid()

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm creating small scratchpad app. The entire app is single column and 3 rows. The row0 will have a close button aligned to the right, row1 is the Text area and row2 will have a few buttons to format the text + 1 button to delete/clear the text area. I want that delete/clear button to align to the right while the rest of the buttons will align to the left such that there's a space between the format buttons and the delete button. So that you don't accidentally clear the text. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

wn = tk.Tk()
wn.attributes('-type', 'splash')
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('top.TFrame', border=0, borderwidth=0, background='green')
style.configure('bottom.TFrame', border=0, borderwidth=0, background='blue')
style.configure('button.TButton', border=5, borderwidth=5, background='#e6e497', bd=5)

root = ttk.Frame(wn, style='top.TFrame', borderwidth=5, relief='ridge')
button = ttk.Button(root, text='X', width=3, command=lambda: wn.destroy(), style='button.TButton')
txt = tk.Text(root, width=40, background='light yellow', bd=5)

bottom = ttk.Frame(root, style='bottom.TFrame', width=2000, borderwidth=5, relief='ridge')
bottombuttona = ttk.Button(bottom, width=3, text='A')
bottombuttonb = ttk.Button(bottom, width=3, text='B')
bottombuttonc = ttk.Button(bottom, width=3, text='C')
bottombuttond = ttk.Button(bottom, width=3, text='D')
bottombuttone = ttk.Button(bottom, width=3, text='E')

root.grid()
button.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.E, ipady=4)
txt.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)
bottom.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)

bottombuttona.grid(column=0, row=2, ipady=5)
bottombuttonb.grid(column=1, row=2, ipady=5)
bottombuttonc.grid(column=2, row=2, ipady=5)
bottombuttond.grid(column=3, row=2, ipady=5)
bottombuttone.grid(column=4, row=2, ipady=5, sticky=tk.E)

txt.focus_force()
wn.bind('<Escape>', lambda x: wn.destroy())
wn.mainloop()
```

This is the result:

[image]

**Question:** How do I move the `bottombuttone` (E) to the right of the `bottom` frame it is in (blue colored)? `sticky` doesn't seem to work

secondary question: what's the purpose of the `width` option in the `Frame` class? doesn't seem to have any impact on the size of the frame itself, despite setting it to 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grid_columnconfigure` to get it to work:

```
...
bottombuttond.grid(column=3, row=2, ipady=5)
bottom.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight = 1)
bottombuttone.grid(column=4, row=2, ipady=5, sticky=tk.E)
...
```

Setting the weight of the last item to 1 allows it to expand to fill it's parent. Using `sticky = tk.E`, it will stick to the right of it's parent.
I made this to demonstrate how grid weights work. The blue is the parent, C1-3 are the child widgets.
[image: Example of tkinter weight]

Comment: Thank you! now i'm starting to understand the layout concepts.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: I have another minor issue. when you click on a button, a grey dotted border appears on around it (on ubuntu 20.04). Do you happen to know how to disable that? I couldn't find an option in the style that works

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40169064) help?